# Carousel; Maximum Items It Will Display

Tags: limit, carousel, posts

Ok. This is the issue: I created twenty seven posts with featured images. The carousel displayed only seven of them.

This is the question: Does the carousel has a limit of posts it will display? If it does, can I modify it?

Your guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the Carousel will display as many images as posts I allow per page. Could this behavior be overridden?

Comment: Which carousel plugin are you using?